# Django custom admin widget subclassing ForeignKeyRawIdWidget

Tags: django, widget, admin, subclass

I am trying to create a custom admin widget which will be used in several different models to display a custom ForeignKey to an Image model. The goal is to display a thumbnail next to the ForeignKey input field. I have been following the blog post [here](https://cmljnelson.blog/2018/10/26/making-a-django-custom-model-field-form-field-and-widget/) but am running into the error:

```
ValueError at /admin/events/event/2697/change/
Cannot assign "11": "Event.image" must be a "Image" instance.
```

It looks like the `save_form_data` method in `django.forms.models` is expecting an instance of the Image model, rather than the id, but I'm not sure how to pass this via my custom model field, or form field. Here is the code:

```
class ImageForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None, image=''):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        html = self._render(self.template_name, context, renderer)
        if value:
            image = Image.objects.get(id=value)
            thumb = image.version_url('thumb')
            image = f'''
                <div style="margin-top: 5px !important;">
                <a href="{image.file.url}">
                <img style='border: solid 1px #ccc;' src="{thumb}"/>
                </a>
                </div>'''
        return mark_safe(html + image)

    def _render(self, template_name, context, renderer=None):
        if renderer is None:
            renderer = get_default_renderer()
        return mark_safe(renderer.render(template_name, context))


class ImageFormField(fields.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, model=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageFormField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget = ImageForeignKeyWidget(model._meta.get_field('image').remote_field, admin.site)


class ImageModelField(models.ForeignKey):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': ImageFormField,
            'model': self.model
            }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return models.Field.formfield(self, **defaults)
```

Is there another method somewhere that needs to be overriden in order to pass in the instance?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a ModelChoiceField and define a queryset:

```
class ImageFormField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def init(self, model=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageFormField, self).init(queryset=None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.widget = ImageForeignKeyWidget(model._meta.get_field('image').remote_field, admin.site)
        self.queryset = Image.objects.all()
```